# Add Input field in Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment link and I need to add a new field in my case a User ID in the checkout form. Which I think is not possible.

**Use Case** :
We are providing email marketing services. We are selling campaigns through two different domains so when customer purchase the campaign via stripe link I need to know which account I need to copy this campaign. So what should I do? Should I use Stripe Elements or create new Stripe checkout session rather than using links?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can’t add custom fields on Payment Link or Checkout Session.

Depending on your use case, you may have several options to track you campaign:

- Create a form on your website that collect your custom data and then redirect the user to Stripe Checkout Session https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata or PaymentLink https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create#create_payment_link-metadata with **metadata**
- Use UTM Code https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#utm-codes with a single PaymentLink
- Create your own form with a custom field (aka User ID) and use Stripe PaymentElement in order to collect the payment